# How to setup a link from an Access .accdb file to a mdb file with user level security?

Tags: security, ms-access, linked-tables

We use in a company an Access database which I developed a long time ago with front end and back end .mdb files and user level security. (We don't need high security standards)

Now I am developing an extension to that database which is mostly independent but has to access some tables of the backend mdb file with user level security.

Is it possible to setup linked tables in an accdb file to a mdb file with user level security? (I tried and it seems it does not work)

If not, is there a big disadvantage to convert a half developed .accdb database into a .mdb database so that it's possible to access the .mdb file with user level security?

Comment: Disadvantage to conversion is some features utilized in accdb will not be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the access application with a custom shortcut and add the /workgroup swtich that specifies the path to the workgroup file. This then should allow you to freely link + consume to the linked mdb file.

Comment: I confirm this works. Thanks a lot! My shortcut looks like this:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "D:\Data\NewDb.accdb" /wrkgrp "D:\Data\OldSecurityFile.mdw"